# Avoid creating app with flask-cli

Tags: python, flask, python-click

I'm using a custom manage.py script for my flask app, which is created with a factory pattern.

This script needs to both be able to run the server and run my tests. I use an external tool to run my tests, so I do not need to create an app to run the tests. How can I only create the app when running certain commands?

My script currently looks like:

```
import subprocess
import sys

from flask import current_app
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
import click

from quizApp import create_app


@click.pass_context
def get_app(ctx, _):
    """Create an app with the correct config.
    """
    return create_app(ctx.find_root().params["config"])


@click.option("-c", "--config", default="development",
              help="Name of config to use for the app")
@click.group(cls=FlaskGroup, create_app=get_app)
def cli(**_):
    """Define the top level group.
    """
    pass


@cli.command("test")
def test():
    """Set the app config to testing and run pytest, passing along command
    line args.
    """
    # This looks stupid, but see
    # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1357
    sys.exit(subprocess.call(['py.test',
                              '--cov=quizApp',
                              '--flake8',
                              '--pylint',
                              './']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

I tried creating a second group, but it seemed that only one group can "run" at a time, so I'm not exactly sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `with_appcontext` parameter to your additional commands:

```
@click.group(cls=FlaskGroup, create_app=get_app)
def cli(**_):
    pass

@cli.command(with_appcontext=false)
def extra():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add:

```
cli.add_command(test)
```

before:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

And I am not sure if it is the only left thing you need to do. I am also study this and feel confused. But if you want to add a command in the FlaskGroup, you must do that. I feel confused when I want to use Factory and CLI in the flask project. Maybe at last you need to try Flask-Script extension, at least it works.